# Powershell multiline regex

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to get full error with line from following example:

```
date time somemethod EXC somenumber sometext  R:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at sometext in somepath .cs:line somenumber System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at sometext in Somepath .cs:line somenumber
```

From that, I'd like to get everything after `EXC` up to `cs:line somenumber`.

`01/01/01 date (mode) (status) (somenumber) (name+error)`, right here there's usually a new line which continues with error message, which ends on characters cs:line (number).

I managed to get error message as it always starts with EXC (so regex is `EXC .*`, however im unable to get full message with code. I have access to PowerShell 2.0 only, I'm using following formula:

```
$Filecontent = [io.file]::Readalltext("path to file")
$filecontent | select-string 'EXC .*' -allmatches |
  foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value} > errors.txt
```

What I need is to get full error with line number but I have problem with proper regular expression. I do not care about the date,time,mode, regex should get EXC status and take full message with line.

After using regex 'EXC .*\n.*cs:line [0-9]{0,99}' it finds me those messages that after one line are finished with error message, however, sometimes theres more next lines that I'd like to capture as well.
Any ideas?

Comment: typo in formula, fixed:$Filecontent = [io.file]::Readalltext("path to file") $filecontent | select-string 'EXC .' -allmatches | foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value} > errors.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define an error (stack trace) as

- begins with a non-whitespace character in column 1
- spans multiple lines
- every additional line that belongs to the error is indented by 3 spaces

then the regex to capture such a block looks like follows:

```
(?m)^\S.*(\s*^   \S.*)+
```

After you have retrieved a complete stack trace block with that you can pick out line numbers in a second step using something like this:

```
at (.*?) in (.*?):line (\d+)
```

---

The expression breaks down as:

```
(?m)         # inline flag: multiline mode
^            # start-of-line
\S           # a non-whitespace character
.*           # anything up to the end of the line
(            # group 1
  \s*        #   any number of whitespace (this matches newline character)
  ^          #   start-of-line
             #   3 spaces
  \S         #   a non-whitespace character
  .*         #   anything up to the end of the line
)+           # end of group 1, repeat at least once
```

---

Compare: https://regex101.com/r/rW1hD6/1

Comment: I'd like to define it as follows:
-Begins with EXC and one whitespace
-spans multiple lines
-ends with cs:line (number up to four digits)

Comment: My expression captures a superset of those. Make it more specific if you need that, for example by putting `EXC` into the appropriate spot. Or by letting `Select-String` get all stack traces first and then pipe them through `Where-Object`. There are many ways to do this.

Comment: uhm, im probably doing something wrong, but when I use '^\S.*(\s*^   \S.*)+' its not retrieving anything. inside () there are 3 spaces as I understood ?

Comment: Yes, three spaces. Did you notice the "multiline" part? I don't think `Select-String` has a switch for that, but you can enable it in the regex itself by prepending it with `(?m)`, like `(?m)^\S.*(\s*^   \S.*)+`. That switch is crucial, otherwise you can't have multiple `^` in the same expression.

Comment: Great, many thanks Tomalak.
Could you please explain to me this regex as im still learning and all I found is \s is for whitespace and \S is for not white space, and its kind of unclear how it does the job, but this formula:
select-string '(?m)^\S.*(\s*^   \S.*)+' -allmatches | foreach { {$_.Matches} | foreach {$_.Value} > file.txt gets the job done(all types of errors with all new lines and code.

Comment: @BoleslawA No problem, see modified answer. Look at the regex101 link, there is a section that explains the regex as well.

Comment: Great! That was exactly what I needed, thanks Tomalak.
Is there any way I can give you some kind of + for your assistance?

Comment: Yes. Upvote my answer and mark it as accepted. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work